# How to uninstall Adobe Acrobat Reader 32-bits without user confirmation or window confirmation

Tags: windows, power, uninstall, adobe-acrobat, intune

My goal is to switch from Acrobat Reader 32-bit to 64-bit via Intune. Since the 32-bit version of Acrobat Reader currently installed on computers wasn’t installed through Intune, I can’t remove it from Intune. So, I want to use a script via Intune to uninstall the 32-bit version for all users (a PowerShell script in a .intunewin file).

I found this script and modified it a bit:

```
$AllRegAppEntries = Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall,HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.pspath}

# Filter on name
$FilteredApps = $AllRegAppEntries | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -ilike "*Adobe Acrobat Reader*" }

# If criteria is met; uninstall
foreach ($App in $FilteredApps) {
    # Use the application's own uninstall command
    if ($App.UninstallString) {
        # Add /quiet to the uninstall command
        $uninstallCommand = $App.UninstallString -replace '/prompt', '/quiet'
        Write-Host "Running the following command: $uninstallCommand"
        Start-Process -FilePath cmd.exe -ArgumentList "/c $uninstallCommand" -Wait
    }
}
```

When I test it directly in a PowerShell session, I always get the confirmation window for uninstalling Acrobat Reader (to choose to repair or uninstall).

I also tried to uninstall using the /quiet option in the command but without success.

So, I wanted to know if there’s a way to uninstall Adobe Acrobat Reader using a PS script without the confirmation window or else, without modifying the registry (which is dangerous).

Comment: Have you tried something like the following command `wmic product where name="*Reader* call uninstall /nointeractive` ? You can also pass the GUID  to `msiexec /x`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just found a solution to my problem. My script was already using msiexec + “/quiet”, but I had an Acrobat Reader window open and I think that was the problem. I also added “/n”, but I don’t think it’s useful. We just need to make sure the service is not running on the computer to uninstall it.

The final working command : "MsiExec.exe /X{PRODUCT_CODE} /qn" + service not running